# How to compare the size of tf.Variable and scalar in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use `Tensorflow` to build my model, and I want to judge the training step and if the step is larger than `10000`, my loss will change. The follows is part of my code.

```
self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
change = tf.cond(tf.greater(self.step,10000), lambda: True, lambda: False)

if change:
   self.loss =
```

But it meets error as follows:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. 
Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, 
and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned 
on the value of a tensor.
```

Hopefully for help.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to evaluate this tensor first

```
step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
change = tf.cond(tf.greater(step,10000), lambda: True, lambda: False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    if sess.run(change):   
        print('Ok')
```

If you substitute `if sess.run(change)` with `if change` you will get the error you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

If it is tensorflow 2.0 then according to the [doc.](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/autograph) the distinction is handled for us.

That is what it seems to do.

```
@tf.function
def check(x,y):
  return tf.cond(tf.greater(x,y), lambda: True, lambda: False)


print(check(tf.constant(2),2))
```